# Can you replicate matlab's older pseudo-random number generators in python?

Tags: python, matlab, random, statistics, probability

I am trying to analyze random streams of random numbers in python. Specifically I am studying the following pseudo-random streams from matlab: mt19937ar (the Mersenne Twister), mcg16807 (an LCG), and swb2712 (a modified subtract with borrow generator). Here is the [reference page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-controlling-a-random-number-stream.html) for matlab's PRNGs.

I know that the Mersenne Twister is the default generator for randomness used in python and I believe in numpy, mcg16807 should also be replicable since it's an LCG, but I am unsure of how to replicate swb2712 in python as it may be proprietary to matlab and I cannot find the source code. Is what I'm trying to do possible or should I just resort to using matlab and call it a day?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please share what you have tried, along with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I know python is nice and yadda yadda, but if you do in fact have access to MATLAB, wouldn't it be considerably easier to just use it? That way you also ensure that the code you are using to compare whatever you want to compare is exactly the same, and do not risk having some differences in coding, plus you save time

Comment: this will be difficult if since you don't know what modifications where done to the published algorithm. BTW, if you want to reproduce the random numbers produced by Matlab you also have to use the same method for seeding the RNG.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this blog, it seems to be based on the variants of George Marsaglia's ziggurat algorithm (to generate normally distributed random numbers) 
https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2015/05/18/the-ziggurat-random-normal-generator/

Two useful references ...

George Marsaglia and W. W. Tsang, "The ziggurat method for generating random variables." Journal of Statistical Software 5, 1-7, 2000
http://www.jstatsoft.org/v05/i08

Jurgen A. Doornik, "An Improved Ziggurat Method to Generate Normal Random Samples." PDF, Nutfield College, Oxford, 2005
http://www.doornik.com/research/ziggurat.pdf

This presentation also detailed it as swb2712: Modified Subtract-with-Borrow generator, with lags 27 and 12 ... http://profmsaeed.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/MATLAB-V.ppt

Hope this help !

Comment: If anyone happens to stumble across this post in the future, this is the correct solution but replicating the modified algorithms was too much work as in actuality I just needed *enough* numbers to be able to perform statistical analysis on. An easier solution is just to generate a couple hundred thousand/million numbers for each respective rng and store them as variables in matlab. You can then export them as a .DAT file for use in python.

Comment: It is always a compromise of storage vs resources / algo ... the c-code from the paper "The Ziggurat Method for Generating Random Variables" by George Marsaglia and Wai Wan Tsang can be ported to MATLAB (often directly only considering the difference in indexing MATLAB 1 to N while C-code from 0 to N-1. Same for the case of "An Improved Ziggurat Method to Generate Normal Random Samples " by JURGEN A DOORNIK. Actually MATLAB accepts compiled C-code with the mex function. On my TODO list when done I will post it here.

Comment: Jurgen A Doornik Research at https://www.doornik.com/research.html#journals has one entry with Doornik, J.A. (2005). An Improved Ziggurat Method to Generate Normal Random Samples ... Link to his code (zipped) is https://www.doornik.com/research/ziggurat_code.zip this will make things easier.